# How to trigger the Back browser button from a Flex app with deep linking

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

How can I programmatically click the browser's Back button from within my Flex application.

I'm using deep linking to allow the user to navigate back/forth inside my application. I want this to work when BACKSPACE is clicked inside the application as well, but Flex captures BACKSPACE and the browser doesn't get the event. I don't want to implement browsing history myself within the application, naturally.

Any ideas? Can I send BACKSPACE to the containing browser? Can I specifically invoke "BACK" in the browser from javascript maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try a JavaScript/Flex bridge.
write a JS function that sends the browser back, and invoke it from within Flex.

have a look at [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2)

Comment: Use ExternalInterface and call javascript function with this content window.history.back();

Comment: Thanks Dan and @zdmytriv, this works for me: `if (ExternalInterface.available) {
    ExternalInterface.call("window.history.back()")
   }
   else {
       Alert.show("Please use the Back button in your web browser.", "Back");
      }`